# Why is the LHS the condition and the RHS the output for dplyr's case_when()?

Tags: r, dplyr, switch-statement

In a regression or plotting context, the formula/tilde syntax is used to mean something like *"The value of the LHS is dependent on the RHS"*. For example

```
lattice::xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)
```

displays `disp` as the x/independent variable and `mpg` as the y/dependent variable. However with dplyr::case_when() this logic seems reversed. The LHS contains the condition, while the RHS contains what is returned if the condition is TRUE. Hence the RHS is dependent on the LHS. Why is this dependency relationship reveresed for case_when() compared to other uses of formula syntax in R? Which is perhaps a different way of asking, why is my interpretation of what case_when() is doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my theory. `case_when` extends `else_if`, and aims to be a `if-then-else` (`case-when-else`) that SQL and other language have. Think of `~` as a shortcut for `then`.

Looking at the source code
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/c2a3fca9ab85dd847605c7fda1d6b0b971f9381a/R/case-when.R
`case_when` uses the function meaning of `~` as a method to split the arguments, see docs for `?rlang::f_lhs()`.

Finally, this format is about readability, I've written several long data clean-up scripts with multiline `case_when`'s, and they are readable thanks to this layout.

Comment: I get that it is about readability, and reading ~ as "then" works, but I still feel that that this swaps the lhs and rhs compared to how it is read in other contexts.